# Create a UTC timestamp in ISO format

Tags: javascript

I need to create a UTC timestamp which is in ISO format

I tried:

```
new Date().getTime().toISOString();
```

But I get `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).getTime(...).toISOString is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do `new Date().toISOString();`

Answer (score 0):

[getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns the number of milliseconds since 1970, which is a number. `toISOString()` is a method of the `Date` object. you just want `new Date().toISOString()`.